# Parse-Server Facebook login - link users with Business Mapping API?

Tags: facebook-login, parse-server

I'm Using ParseServer with two different client applications. Since each mobile app is associated with a different Facebook app (different app names, logos...), the current Facebook policy is to issue a foreign user id for same users when authenticating through different Facebook apps.

We'd like to link those two user ids in ParseServer so they will share a single user account. Even when authenticating via different Facebook apps.

According to Facebook documentation the way to do that is by using the token_for_business or "Business Mapping API" to match two user IDs that belong to a single user.

However, ParseServer documentation does not indicate how to use token_for_business or "Business Mapping API".

We are currently using the /users (POST) endpoint for login and registration passing the authData structure for Facebook when Facebook auth is performed.

Assuming ParseServer uses the authData.facebook.id attribute in order to look for existing users once a new login request arrives, its possible to call the facebook API GET /me/ids_for_business and substitute the id in authData with a previously existing user id.

1. Is this a recommended approach?
2. Ideally, I'd like to just add my token_for_business to the authData in the login request and have Parse do the rest of the work. Is that supported?
3. Lastly, is it at all possible to link two facebook users in ParseServer? the authData structure does not seem to allow is as the "facebook" id section is no in any type of array - it seems there is no way to express dual facebook ids under a single user.. Is this changed at any future parse version (currently using Parse 1.6.14 in the client and ParseServer 2.2.19)

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Currently planning to implement a workaround like this: after client obtains a facebook user id and access token, pass control over to the server where Graph API used to validate the token and to query for alternate user ids (using /me/ids_for_business) If alternate user ids are found, and a a user is found for one of them, we write the newly acquired id and token under the preexisting user's authData (either by calls to link() or otherwise accessing the database). After this, login will proceed as today.

Comment: Issue discussed [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4415)

Comment: Hi, any updates on that plan? From what I understand, simply updating the pre-existing user is not enough: how would you tell Parse to also actually return the pre-existing user ID to the client? Validating the authData in an authenticator is not enough, am I wrong?

Comment: we have implemented this by wrapping the login command. if it's a facebook authData, we validate it, look for a matching user in the User class. if none found we get all alternate user id's for this end user from facebook API, and then repeat the query against User class to find a possible user entry. if a user entry is found now, we just write over her authData, and save. Once all this is done we pass control to the underlying Parse.login() which will then succeed in locating the user since we've already made sure the authData will match.

Comment: yeah, ended up patching Parse's code as well, modifying the relevant methods of RestWrite